# fixed div scroll content heights using percentage %

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to scroll content in a fixed div, anyone got any magic they can apply ???

```
html, body {
width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
.top {
height:50%;
background-color:blue;
width:100%; 
}
.fixed {
position:fixed;
padding: 0;
top: 50%;
width:100%; 
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
font-size:26px; 
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajrashid/LLZ4g/1/

Comment: What issue are you having with it?

Comment: You’re getting a scrollbar on the document, because you did not eliminate the default margins for `html`/`body` – therefor, your `.top` element with its 100% width forces a horizontal scrollbar, and that in turn because of the height of the content forces a vertical scrollbar as well, partly hiding the scrollbar for the fixed element; and you are making your fixed element to high as well. Set `margin:0` for `html, body`, and for `.fixed` remove the `height` and add `bottom:0` instead, and the problem should be gone. http://jsfiddle.net/LLZ4g/3/

Comment: awesome, educated.... why haven't you submitted as answer man ???

Comment: question understand everything, u said except why bottom:0 makes it scroll-able in this case ?.

Comment: Could you tell me the issue:Tell if this code solves your problem [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/LLZ4g/4/)

Comment: @Shadow, cant test as you've removed the autoscroll links & javascript

Comment: @saj:What did you mean by auto scroll link ?.i did not understand ..

Comment: @SHadow, if you see my orignal fiddle, in the blue area there are 3 links that controll the scrolling